# What is the analog of Query in python?

Tags: query, python

Is there an analog of Query[] in Python 3.8+?

Comment: This is not really a WL question, is it? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask within Python community? SO maybe?

Comment: Take a look at documentation > details for Query, it has a lot of features, do you want a solution that fits them all?

Comment: I wish python had its own stack exchange

Comment: Stack overflow tag \[python\] is what you wish.

Comment: No too messy, should have its own sse

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is fundamentally a python question, not a Mathematica one.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.query('age < 25')
```

is the same as

```
df[df['age'] < 25]
```

in `python 2.7`.

so `Cases` may be equivalent to this.

the following is example.

preparing the dataframe,

```
df = {};
Do[
  AppendTo[
    df, <|"name" -> 
      StringJoin@RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 5],
      "age" -> RandomInteger[{1, 40}], 
     "sex" -> RandomChoice[{"male", "female"}]|>];, {20}];
```

then,

```
Cases[df, KeyValuePattern[{"age" -> x_ /; x <= 25}]] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]